# Block autohotkeys from being injected into my website

Tags: jquery, security

I have a website that allows users to gain points by clicking a button repeatedly for their team (simple idea).

However, there seems to be a way for users to inject a script or use a program called Autohotkeys that lets them automate the clicking process.

Is there a way I can block this from happening, whether that be through a script or tips to help prevent?

Comment: autohotkey is an external program that they are presumably using as an autoclicker. I have a feeling that any attempt of blocking its use by setting a maximum click rate is only going to lead to a game of cat and mouse between you and cheaters, though.

Comment: A rudimentary method might be to keep time interval measurements of the last n clicks and if they are all within a close margin, or not humanly possible then assume it's an autoclicker. Though there's also macro options on some keyboard/mice that would allow for repeated clicking - even binding mouse wheel to a click can give very fast clicks.

Comment: As stated above since this is an external program there really is no way for your website to determine if they are *actually* clicking or if a program is clicking for them. Theres just no way to do it.